# Redis ERR wrong number of arguments for 'save' command

Tags: redis, nest

I am trying to us cache on my backend app with redis but in the very moment I use the save function it comes with this error:

`ERR wrong number of arguments for 'save' command`

This is the save function in the redis service:

```
async save(key: string, value: string) {
    console.log('Enotro ak redisDataService');
    await this.redisClient.set(key, value);
    return false;
}
```

This the code where I have being trying to use it:

```
async findAll() {
    const findTypeIdent = await this.typeIdentRepository.find();
    const redi = await this.redisDataService.save('key_test',JSON.stringify(findTypeIdent))
    return redi
}
```

I am using

`Redis server v=7.2.0`

Can you help me to know what is happening please?

Comment: What client library are you using to connect to Redis? And what version?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message it looks like it's the Redis `save` command that's get sent to Redis and not the `set` command.